# Is it possible to create firebase user using RestSharp?

Tags: c#, vb.net, firebase, firebase-authentication, restsharp

I just knew about the RestSharp and started exploring it.
I could find how to "Log-in" using a user already created doing this:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://example.com");
client.Authenticator = new SimpleAuthenticator("username", "foo", "password", "bar");

var request = new RestRequest("resource", Method.GET);
client.Execute(request);
```

But is there a way of actually creating a user in the firebase using the Restshart? Equivilant to this using the Firebase object in JAVA

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
ref.createUser({email:"bobtony@firebase.com",password:"correcthorsebatterystaple"});
```

I know it is possible to create a node for emails/passwords and manage them manually, but I would like to use the Firebase users auths.

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean?

Comment: This has absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with Java, and I'm skeptical about the VB.NET.

Comment: RestSharp is a component for C#, but with a little code coversion I am able to use it in VB.NET which I prefer. In regards to JAVA I put it there because the code above is in JAVA. I hope you are happy now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the library is called RestSharp, it likely builds on top of the [Firebase Legacy REST API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/). That API does not have functionality to create users.